# Existe alguma API / Web Service que forneça os nomes dos carros existentes?

Tags: web-service, api

Preciso que seja uma lista atualizada, com todos os modelos de carros, classificados por marca.

Estou desenvolvendo um site de classificados e preciso disso para a filtragem de resultados.

Existe alguma agência ou órgão que forneça isso?

Comment: Tente entrar em contato no email no fim da página e ver se eles oferecem algo: http://veiculos.fipe.org.br

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É difícil encontrar pessoas ou empresas que queiram realmente fornecer essas informações, no entanto conheço o [**CarQuery**](http://www.carqueryapi.com/) que é uma API baseada em JSON fácil de usar para recuperar informação detalhada de carro e caminhão, incluindo ano, marca, modelo, guarnição e outras especificações.

Como nada é de graça nesse mundo, talvez você tenha que desembolar alguns *moneys* para utiliza-la dependendo da pretensão e objetivo do seu projeto.

Veja mais detalhes [na documentação](http://www.carqueryapi.com/documentation/).

Também existe o [**automotive-model-year-data**](https://github.com/n8barr/automotive-model-year-data) porém de 2014, e realmente talvez, eu digo talvez, não vai ser atualizado por causa do custo para manter essas informações.

Comment: Consegue achar um Gol 1000 ou Fiat Palio nela?

Comment: @Bacco versão FULL talvez, eu digo talvez, tenha. hehehe

Comment: kkk. só dei um toque pq provavelmente pro autor vai fazer falta :)

Comment: @Bacco hoje dia com money quase tudo é possível. Eu digo quase!

Comment: Dinheiro não traz felicidade (mas com ele você pode ficar infeliz com comida, conforto, menos preocupação e provavelmente mais saúde do que se não tivesse o dinheiro kkkkk).